# Maxima/minima and monotonicity of $y(x)$ if $y(x)$ is solution of differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-1+\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, maxima-minima, monotone-functions

On the open interval $(-c,c)$, where $c$ is a positive real number, $y(x)$ is an infinitely differentiable solution of the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-1+\cos x$$ with the initial condition $y(0)=0$. Then which one of the following is correct?

(A) $y(x)$ has a local maximum at the origin

(B) $y(x)$ has a local minimum at the origin

(C) $y(x)$ is strictly increasing on the open interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ for some positive real number $\delta$

(D)$y(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the open interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ for some positive real number $\delta$

**My Attempt**

Since $y(0)=0$ and function is differentiable and hence continuous so it should be very close to $0$ in the neighborhood of $x=0$. So $y^2+\cos x$ could be greater than $1$ in the neighborhood of $x=0$.On the other hand the opposite may as well be true.So, $(C)$ or $(D)$ may be correct. But what will be actual/logical explanation.

Comment: You can compute the higher order derivatives either by using derivatives of the equation or by inserting a power series for $y$ and comparing coefficients of equal degree.

Comment: @LutzLehmannI got $y'(0)=y''(0)=0$ and $y'''(0)=-1$. Can we deduce something from this.

Comment: @LutzLehmann    I think i got it. $y'''(x)<0$ in neighborhood of $x=0$ so $y''(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$. So for $x<0$ we have $y''(x)>y''(0)$ i.e $y''(x)>0$ and for $x>0$ we have $y''(x)<0$. So concavity of $y=y(x)$ changes from positive to negative across $x=0$. So $y'(x)$ must be negative. Hence, the answer must be the option (D). Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

The equation and initial condition are invariant under inflection $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,-y)$. Thus this specific IVP solution has to be an odd-symmetric function.

The leading lowest-degree terms in $y=a_mx^m+...$ has to satisfy
$$
ma_mx^{m-1}+...=a_m^2x^{2m}+...-\frac12x^2+...
$$
which implies $m=3$, $3a_m=-\frac12$.

Comment: Can you explain how $m=3$? I am not getting the reason.

Comment: Because the lowest power comes from the cosine term, thus $m-1=2$. In the other balance identity, $m-1=2m$, one gets $m=-1$, which does not give a solution (that is bounded at $x=0$).

Comment: Correct...I got $y(x)=-\frac{-1}{6}x^3+...$, but still I am not able to say any thing about monotonicity in some nbd of $0$. From the equation I can say $0$ is a point of inflection and thereby it is neither maximum nor minimum. In fact, I want to know about the sign of $y'$ near zero. @LutzLehmann

Comment: For a sufficiently small neighborhood, the leading term dominates all the following terms. So this is already sufficient to answer c) and d). Also, it can be read of from the DE that the leading term of $y'$ is $-\frac12x^2$, as $y=O(x^3)$, $y^2=O(x^6)$ only influences higher-order terms.

Comment: Its clear now...thnks...